# add_meta_box does not go 'side'

Tags: metabox

I'm trying to add some metabox to my custom post type. So I add this:

```
add_meta_box(
    'my_custom_meta_box_id', 
    'My-meta-box-title',
    'my_custom_meta_box_callback', 
    'my-custom-post-type', 
    'side', 
    'default'
);
```

So the meta-box keep showing at bottom left. What could cause that problem?

Comment: The metabox was added in a different context before? If so, the metabox position is probably saved as user option and so keep showing on main column, even if now it is added on the sidebar. Try to create another test user, log in with this new user and metabox should appear in sidebar. If my guess is correct, for the user the view sidebar on the left, simply move it manually on the right.

Comment: Once this function is ran, does it need to be left in the code? Actually manually moving is pretty good! Didn't know about that! Thanks!

Comment: With the function in OP new users or existing users had bever vieved the metabox before, will se the metabox on the sidebar. If you are the only and unique user of the site, move it where you want, and don't care about that.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just that behavior is strange.First it was side and then somehow it went bottom. Now I know. Thanks mate, case closed.

Answer (score 2):

This might be caused because you have tried to move your custom meta box to some place and Wordpress respects the user's ordering/positioning of these boxes. You can do as [gmazzap](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162071/add-meta-box-does-not-go-side/345411#comment234364_162071) has told because this will create a new user with blank preferences.

Or you can login to your database, find `DBPREFIX_usermeta` (`DBPREFIX` is your database prefix) and find related database entries. In my case:

[image: db entries for custom ordering of user]

You can see `meta-box-order_PLUGINNAME` (where it is your plugin's name) and `screen_layout_PLUGINNAME`. When I removed these entries, the problem was gone.